# How do I signal a std::thread to exit gracefully?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

Using C++17, for a worker thread with a non-blocking loop in it that performs some task, I see three ways to signal the thread to exit:

1. A `std::atomic_bool` that the thread checks in a loop. If it is set to `true`, the thread exits. The main thread sets it to `true` before invoking `std::thread::join()`.
2. A `std::condition_variable` with a `bool`. This is similar to the above, except it allows you to invoke `std::condition_variable::wait_for()` to effectively "sleep" the thread (to lower CPU usage) while it waits for a potential exit signal (via setting the `bool`, which is checked in the 3rd argument to `wait_for()` (the predicate). The main thread would lock a mutex, change the bool to `true`, and invoke `std::condition_variable::notify_all()` before invoking `std::thread::join()` to signal the thread to exit.
3. A `std::future` and `std::promise`. The main thread holds a `std::promise<void>` while the worker thread holds the corresponding `std::future<void>`. The worker thread uses `std::future::wait_for()` similar to the step above. Main thread invokes `std::promise::set_value()` before calling `std::thread::join()`.

My thoughts on each:

1. This is simple, but lacks the ability to "slow down" the worker thread loop without explicitly calling `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`. Seems like an "old fashioned" way of doing thread signals.
2. This one is comprehensive, but very complicated, because you need a condition variable plus a boolean variable.
3. This one seems like the best option, because it has the simplicity of #1 without the verbosity of #2. But I have no personal experience with `std::future` and `std::promise` yet, so I am not sure if it's the ideal solution. In my mind, promise & future are meant to transfer values across threads, not really be used as signals. So I'm not sure if there are efficiency concerns.

I see multiple ways of signaling a thread to exit. And sadly, my Google searching has only introduced more as I keep looking, without actually coming to a general consensus on the "modern" and/or "best" way of doing this with C++17.

I would love to see some light shed on this confusion. Is there a conclusive, definitive way of doing this? What is the general consensus? What are the pros/cons of each solution, if there is no "one size fits all"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198748/discussion-on-question-by-void-pointer-how-do-i-signal-a-stdthread-to-exit-gra).

Comment: Why use a std::atomic<bool> if the bool only changes state once?  It's not used for synchronization, but for simple signaling.  using a std::atomic<bool> will slow down your looping code uselessly.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Do you have a link you can provide that explains why?

Comment: It's true for x86.  It's due to how the cache hardware operates. If you plan to have your software run on ARM, ypou may still want to use std::atomic.  My preferred way to signal thread exit in Windows is to use a native event and WaitForMultipleObjects().  Avoid polling as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a busy working thread which requires one-way notification if it should stop working the best way is to just use an `atomic<bool>`. It is up to the worker thread if it wants to slow down or it doesn't want to slow down. The requirement to "throttle" the worker thread is completely orthogonal to the thread cancellation and, in my opinion, should not be considered with the cancellation itself. This approach, to my knowledge, has 2 drawbacks: you can't pass back the result (if any) and you can't pass back an exception (if any). But if you do not need any of those then use `atomic<bool>` and don't bother with anything else. It is as modern as any; there is nothing old-fashioned about it.

`condition_variable` is part of the consumer/producer pattern. So there is something which produces work and there is something that consumes what was produced. To avoid busy waiting for the consumer while there is nothing to consume the `condition_variable` is a great option to use. It is just a perfect primitive for such tasks. But it doesn't make sense for the thread cancellation process. And you will have to use another variable anyway because you can't rely on `condition_variable` alone. It might spuriously wake up the thread. You might "set" it before it gets in the waiting process, losing the "set" completely, and so on. It just can't be used alone so we back to square one but now with an `atomic<bool>` variable to accompany our `condition_variable`

The `future`/`promise` pair is good when you need to know the result of the operation done on the other thread. So it is not a replacement of the approach with the `atomic<bool>` but it rather complements it. So to remove the drawbacks described in the first paragraph you add `future`/`promise` to the equation. You provide the calling side with the `future` extracted from the `promise` which lives within the thread. That `promise` gets set once the thread is finished:

- Because exception is thrown.
- Because thread has done its work and completed on its own.
- Because we asked it to stop by setting the `atomic<bool>` variable.

So as you see the `future`/`promise` pair just helps to provide some feedback for the callee it has nothing to do with the cancellation itself.

P.S. You can always use an electric sledgehammer to crack a nut but it doesn't make the approach any more modern.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is conclusive, or definitive, but since this is somewhat an opinion question, I'll give an answer that it is based upon a lot of trial and error to solve the kind of problem you are asking about (I think).

My preferred pattern is to signal the thread to stop using atomic bool, and control the 'loop' timing with a condition variable.

We ran into the requirement for running repeating tasks on worker threads so often that we created a class that we called 'threaded_worker'.  This class handles the complexities of aborting the thread, and timing the calls to the worker function.

The abort is handled via a method that sets the atomic bool 'abort' signal which tells the thread to stop calling the work function and terminate.

The loop timing can be controlled by methods that set the wait time for the condition variable.  The thread can be released to continue via method that calls the notify on the condition variable.

We use the class as a base class for all kinds of objects that have some function that needs to execute on a separate thread.  The class is designed to run the 'work' function once, or in a loop.

We use the bool for the abort, because it is simple and suitable to do the job.  We use the condition variable for loop timing, because it has the benefit of being notified to 'short circuit' the timing.  This is very useful when the threaded object is a consumer.  When a producer has work for the threaded object, it can queue the work and notify that the work is available.  The threaded object immediately continues, instead of waiting for the specified wait time on the condition variable.

The reason for both (the abort signal, and the condition variable) is that I see terminating the thread as one function, and timing the loop as another.

We used to time loops by putting the thread to sleep for some duration.  This made it almost impossible to get predictable loop timing on Windows computers.  Some computers will return from sleep(1) in about 1ms, but others will return in 15ms.  Our performance was highly dependent on the specific hardware.  Using condition variables we have greatly improved the timing of critical tasks.  The added benefit of notifying a waiting thread when work is available is more than worth the complexity of the condition variable.

Comment: P.S.  I don't care for promise/future.